# Кодировка на php

Tags: кодировка, php

Добрый день! Постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой кодировки, возьмем браузер google chorme и опишу процесс на этом браузере. Создаю какой нибудь скрипт, регистрацию и авторизацию пользователя, ставлю кодировку UTF-8 без BOM в notepad++ так же как и вы. Создаю форму и на русском пишу Логин пароль. Вывожу на экран выводятся закорючки. Я ставлю кодировку просто в UTF-8 выводится нормально, но я не смогу работать с сессиями, потому что он в начале ставит по умолчанию тег <br> и выдает ошибку что заголовки были уже отправлены. Как быть в это ситуации. Причем UTF-8 без BOM сессии работают но выводятся закорючки во всех браузерах. ПОМОГИТЕ устал уже от этой проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .htaccess прописать строку:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: а где находиться этот файл, у меня стандартный apache и выводится по поиску слишком много файлов.

Comment: В корне сайта создаете такой файлик. Файл не имеет имени, а только расширение **.htaccess** . Создать его можно и обычным блокнотом - "Сохранить как" > "Тип файла: все файлы" > и прописываете ".htaccess"

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!+

Comment: @duddeniska, вот и хорошо. А страницы - UTF-8 без BOM!

Comment: да да оно самое! А то блин с сессиями не поработаешь а так все работает и по умолчанию!